# Atomic Writes to Cassandra with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, atomic, spark-cassandra-connector

I am fairly new to both Cassandra (2.1.11) and Spark (1.4.1) and am interested in knowing if anyone has seen/developed a solution for atomic writes to two different Cassandra tables using Spark Streaming.

I currently have two tables which hold the same data set, but have different partition keys. For simplicity sake, I'll use the familiar User table example to explain:

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.user_by_user_id
(
    user_id uuid
    ,email_address text
    ,num int //a value that is frequently updated
    ,PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE schema1.user_by_email_address
(
    email_address text
    ,user_id uuid
    ,num int //a value that is frequently updated
    ,PRIMARY KEY (email_address)
);
```

The `email_address` column will have a high cardinality (in reality it will be between 50% and 100% of the number of `user_id` values). High cardinality makes secondary indexes perform poorly, thus requiring the second table.

I am using Spark Streaming to process changes in the `num` column and update these two tables. As I understand it, the `saveToCassandra()` method executes writes for each item in the RDD in an UNLOGGED BATCH, thus performing atomic writes (as explained in the "Save a Collection of Objects" section [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md)). However, `saveToCassandra()` can only be used to save to a single table. In order to keep both the `schema1.user_by_user_id` and `schema1.user_by_email_address` tables in sync, I have to issue two separate `saveToCassandra()` calls:

```
rdd.saveToCassandra("schema1","user_by_user_id",SomeColumns("user_id","email"address","num"))
rdd.saveToCassandra("schema1","user_by_email_address",SomeColumns("user_id","email"address","num"))
```

The writes ocurring within each call are done in an atomic manner, but the two calls together are not atomic. Some error in the second call will leave the two tables out of sync.

Obviously my data set and actual table structures are more complicated than this, but I've tried to convey the main points of my problem in as simple a way as possible. While my question is geared towards being able to save to two tables, I would welcome any alternative suggestions regarding data model changes which would completely remove this need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to understand: **UNLOGGED** batches are *not* atomic.  See [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html).  The only thing **UNLOGGED** batches give you is the ability to make multiple writes all with the same timestamp.

So, if you want to make multiple calls to `saveToCassandra` and have them behave as if it were one call, just [specify the WRITETIME](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#specifying-ttl-and-writetime) to both calls.  When everything is done, all of the modified data will have the same timestamp.

As for your question of how to make updates to multiple tables atomic...you can't.  Cassandra doesn't support it.

The best suggestion I can think of, is to create your own sort of batch log that you can consult after a crash to figure out what needs to be re-synchronized.

Imagine something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE batch_log
(
    id uuid,
    updated_users set<uuid>,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

When starting your job, generate a new uuid that will be the id of this job.  Then, you'd issue 3 saves:

```
rdd.saveToCassandra("schema1", "batch_log", SomeColumns("batch_id", "user_id" append)
rdd.saveToCassandra("schema1","user_by_user_id",SomeColumns("user_id","email"address","num"))
rdd.saveToCassandra("schema1","user_by_email_address",SomeColumns("user_id","email"address","num"))
```

If your batch completes without any crashes, you can just delete the `batch_log` row that was created.
However, if the system crashes partway through, then once things are back online, you can consult the `batch_log` to get a list of users which were updated.  Go query those users for their email address and then update the `user_by_email_address` table.  Once you finish this repair, you can delete your `batch_log`.

In effect you are implementing "by hand" a Cassandra **LOGGED** BATCH.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I missed the fact that removal of the writes to the batchlog to avoid the perfomance hit removes atomicity. As for the workaround, I think this is a great solution for what I need.